# Compact Framework: drawing multi-line string with ellipses

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, drawstring

I'm creating an owner-drawn control inherited from ListView for a Windows Mobile application. I'm using `Graphics.DrawString` to write out a two-line text string (using .NET CF 3.5). Problem is some items have particularly long text that doesn't fit on the two lines. Googling has found methods for using `MeasureString` and to manually truncate my string, but this only works on a single-line string. Is there any way to get the ellipses here, or do I have to either accept clipped text or redesign to use only a single line? (Neither is a deal-breaker, but ellipses sure would be nice.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get the ellipses to display, but you'll have to do some P/Invoking (what's new?):

```
public static void DrawText(Graphics gfx, string text, Font font, Color color, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
 IntPtr hdcTemp = IntPtr.Zero;
 IntPtr oldFont = IntPtr.Zero;
 IntPtr currentFont = IntPtr.Zero;

 try
 {
  hdcTemp = gfx.GetHdc();
  if (hdcTemp != IntPtr.Zero)
  {
   currentFont = font.ToHfont();
   oldFont = NativeMethods.SelectObject(hdcTemp, currentFont);

   NativeMethods.RECT rect = new NativeMethods.RECT();
   rect.left = x;
   rect.top = y;
   rect.right = x + width;
   rect.bottom = y + height;

   int colorRef = color.R | (color.G << 8) | (color.B << 16);
   NativeMethods.SetTextColor(hdcTemp, colorRef);

   NativeMethods.DrawText(hdcTemp, text, text.Length, ref rect, NativeMethods.DT_END_ELLIPSIS | NativeMethods.DT_NOPREFIX);
  }
 }
 finally
 {
  if (oldFont != IntPtr.Zero)
  {
   NativeMethods.SelectObject(hdcTemp, oldFont);
  }

  if (hdcTemp != IntPtr.Zero)
  {
   gfx.ReleaseHdc(hdcTemp);
  }

  if (currentFont != IntPtr.Zero)
  {
   NativeMethods.DeleteObject(currentFont);
  }
 }
}
```

NativeMethods is a class that has all of my native calls.  Including:

```
internal const int DT_END_ELLIPSIS = 32768;
internal const int DT_NOPREFIX = 2048;


[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int DrawText(IntPtr hDC, string Text, int nLen, ref RECT pRect, uint uFormat);

[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int SetTextColor(IntPtr hdc, int crColor);

[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hDC, IntPtr hObject);

[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct RECT
{
 public int left;
 public int top;
 public int right;
 public int bottom;

}
```

Comment: I was afraid P/Invoke would be involved. But great answer!